# Count forengkey django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I count the likes i got all the count from database. I would like to count only the likes related with an article

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    comments = CommentSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)


class Meta:
    model = Article
    fields = "__all__"

def get_likes(self, value):
    return Vote.objects.select_related('article').filter(value=True).count()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try like this:

```
def get_likes(self, obj):
    # if you have related_name='votes' in Vote model
    # then it will be obj.votes.count()
    # else
    return obj.vote_set.count()
```

**Or** you can try an **efficient** solution. For this update queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class API(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.annotate(vote_count=Count('vote'))
```

And change the serializer:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    comments = CommentSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    likes = serializers.IntegerField(
        source='vote_count', 
        read_only=True
    )
```

Reason for this **efficiency** is that it is not querying database for each count, rather doing it once when the queryset is evaluated.